# Removing cached Query from Redis using django-cacheops

Tags: django, django-cache

I am using django-cacheops to cache a Query. And updating some in the same instance with some different API call now I want to remove this cached Query from Redis.
This is **API-1**

```
users = User.objects.cache().get(user_id = user_id)
```

Now I am updating my user with API-2

```
user = request.user
if user.is_sms_read:
    user.is_sms_read = False
else:
    user.is_sms_read = True
user.save()
```

Now I am fetching the data with same API-1
and it is giving me the data cached data 
I want if I call the API-2 it should clear the cache and fetch new data.

Comment: What do you mean by API-1 and API-2? If these have different redis servers then sure they invalidate separately. If these are two have different databases at different django aliases then you may look at `db_agnostic` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official documentation of **django-cacheops** states that it listens on model signals and invalidates "appropriate queries". But it won't invalidate queries that doesn't seem to be affected by the change. It looks like a bug to me as the queryset for API-1 should be affected by the change in API-2. But meanwhile you can also try invalidating the cache forcefully by using

```
from cacheops import invalidate_obj

user = request.user
if user.is_sms_read:
    user.is_sms_read = False
else:
    user.is_sms_read = True
user.save()

invalidate_obj(user)
```